# How can one find a comprehensive enumeration of all the precedent setting cases that pertain to a particular issue or rulings on a given statute?

Tags: legal-research, case-law, research, legal-citation

how can one find a comprehensive enumeration of all the precedent setting cases that pertain to a particular issue or the application of a particular statute?

Comment: What country/location?

Comment: I suppose U.K. / England

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can one become comprehensively aware of all applicable statutes/remedies to a given situation when they are scattered between different acts?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/79756/how-can-one-become-comprehensively-aware-of-all-applicable-statutes-remedies-to)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[new-zealand](/questions/tagged/new-zealand)

The Law Society provides this [research service](https://www.lawsociety.org.nz/professional-practice/law-library/using-the-library/research-services/) where specially trained people scour through all relevant databases and return to you what they have found. Though this service is only available to lawyers (and other people associated with the profession), a lawyer can submit a request for you. Find one that charges in 15-min (or less) time chunks (instead of rounding up to hours) and the price will be reasonable.

Some of the databases are freely available: [NZLII](http://www.nzlii.org/databases.html) and [JDO](https://forms.justice.govt.nz/jdo/Search.jsp), but they are far from being comprehensive.

Comprehensive databases are available commercially e.g. [CaseBase](https://www.lexisnexis.co.nz/lexisadvance/casebase.aspx), though subscriptions typically cost several thousand $ per annum.